# Selenium: Não criar o processo com o Chrome

Tags: selenium-webdriver

estou tentando chamar chrome, já estou com o chromedriver na mesma pasta que o py, porém sempre dá o erro abaixo. Como devo fazer?

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQdqV.png)

Answer (score -2):

Baixe a versão apropriada do Chrome Driver que deve funcionar.
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Como o óbvio também tem de ser dito as vezes, vale lembrar que tu tem que ter o Chrome instalado.

Answer (score -3):

Saudações, acredito que seja necessário a atualização do ChromeDriver, quando desatualizado, normalmente não abre a execução e tem a quebra logo de cara. Espero ter ajudado!